# Delay when loading CSS into shiny server

Tags: r, shiny, loading

First of all, fairly new to Shiny, so bear with me.
I have tried to create R studio shiny page with authorization. First page is login page and if you pass the authorization process (e.g. User and Pass are correct) you are taken to main Shiny page. In reality it just means that two different UI's are rendered.

However since implementing authorization page, CSS code which changes sidebar and header colors, seems to run with delay (as can be seen by running an app, you can notice that Shiny default style is loaded onto a sidebar and later it is overwritten by CSS). What could be the problem here?

Code as follows:

ui.R

```
shinyUI(
fluidPage(

ui <- dashboardPage(

header <- dashboardHeader(uiOutput("header")),
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(uiOutput("sidebarpanel")),
body <- dashboardBody(uiOutput("body"))
)))
```

server.R

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(writexl)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinythemes)
library(openssl)
library(shinyWidgets)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

Logged <- FALSE
USER <<- reactiveValues(Logged = Logged)

my_username <- "demo"
my_password <- "369"

observe({ 
 if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
  if (!is.null(input$Login)) {
    if (input$Login > 0) {
      Username <- isolate(input$userName)
      Password <- isolate(input$passwd)
      Id.username <- which(my_username == Username)
      Id.password <- which(my_password == Password)
      if (length(Id.username) > 0 & length(Id.password) > 0) {
        if (Id.username == Id.password) {
          USER$Logged <<- TRUE
        }}
       else sendSweetAlert(session = session, title = "Incorrect Username or 
       Password!",
                        text = "Please check.", type = "error",
                         btn_labels = "Ok")

         }}}    
     })

    output$body <- renderUI({ 
    dashboardBody(
          tags$style(HTML('
                  /* logo */
                  .skin-blue .main-header .logo {
                  background-color: #FFFFFF;
                  }

                  /* logo when hovered */
                  .skin-blue .main-header .logo:hover {
                  background-color: #FFFFFF;
                  }

                  /* sidebar */
                  .skin-blue .main-sidebar {
                  background-color: #873260;
                  }

                  /* logo when hovered */
                  .skin-blue .main-header .navbar {
                  background-color: #873260;
                  }
                  ')),

   if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
        box(title = "Login",textInput("userName", "Username"),
        passwordInput("passwd", "Password"),
        br(),
        actionButton("Login", "Log in")
    )})
})

    output$sidebarpanel <- renderUI({
      if (USER$Logged == TRUE) { 
        dashboardSidebar( 

                    sidebarMenu(
                      menuItem("Home", icon = icon("home")),
                      menuItem("Panel 1", icon = icon("th-large")),
                      menuItem("Panel 2", icon = icon("dashboard")),
                      menuItem("Panel 3", icon = icon("dashboard")),
                      menuItem("Panel 4", icon = icon("pencil")),
                      menuItem("Panel 5", icon = icon("pencil")),
                      menuItem("Panel 6", icon = icon("th"))
                    )
                  )
  }})
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting styling into ui.R seems to do the trick

```
shinyUI(
fluidPage(

ui <- dashboardPage(

  header <- dashboardHeader(uiOutput("header")),
  sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(uiOutput("sidebarpanel")),
  body <- dashboardBody(      tags$style(HTML('
                                              /* logo */
                                              .skin-blue .main-header .logo {
                                              background-color: #FFFFFF;
                                              }

                                              /* logo when hovered */
                                              .skin-blue .main-header 
                                              .logo:hover {
                                              background-color: #FFFFFF;
                                              }

                                              /* sidebar */
                                              .skin-blue .main-sidebar {
                                              background-color: #873260;
                                              }

                                              /* logo when hovered */
                                              .skin-blue .main-header .navbar {
                                              background-color: #873260;
                                              }
                                              ')),

    uiOutput("body"))
)))
```

Still, it would be nice if someone could explain what caused that delay.

Comment: Really recommend you read and look up documentation for learning shiny - look at a lot of demos and their code to see best practice and you'll have a much easier time. The server code isn't executed until its triggered and that can cause an apparent delay - most styling should be in a seperate css file anyway. I believe nginx can be used as a simple login if thats all you want.